# What is the Correct Javascript Syntax for this

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am trying to call a function within a function. Here is the code

```
var d = function() {
    s: function() {
        alert('cool');
    }
} ();
d.s();
```

This does not work. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach using the so-called [module pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/):

```
var d = function() {
  return {
    s: function() {
      alert('cool');
    }
  };
}();
d.s();  // invokes the function s
```

Answer (score 4):

Erm...  it looks like maybe you're trying to define an **Object** with a function?

In that case,

```
var d = {
  s: function(){
    alert('cool');
  }
};
d.s();  //Invokes the function s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = {
  s: function() {
    alert('cool');
  }
};

d.s();
```